# .info file is not loading the JavaScript code

Tags: 6, theming, javascript

I added the references to some JavaScript files, in my .info file, hoping that they would be output by the `$scripts` variable in my header. I cleared the cache, and they are still not there.

```
$Id$
name = site
base theme = boron
core = 6.x
engine = phptemplate
; We do not have a Left sidebar.
;regions[left] = Left sidebar
; We do not have a right sidebar.
;regions[right] = Right sidebar
regions[content] = Content
regions[header] = Header
regions[footer] = Footer
scripts[] = sitename/sites/all/themes/custom/jivamukti/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js
scripts[] = sitename/sites/all/themes/custom/jivamukti/js/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
```

I put the JavaScript in the root of the themes folder I am using, instead of /js, and now it is output in this function in my header:

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings,…);
```

How do I just get it to display inside the `<script></script>` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file path should be relative to the theme directory not the root directory; try it with `js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js` instead of `sitename/sites/all/themes/custom/jivamukti/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js`.

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Administrator > Site building > Themes"; select the theme, save again, and refresh.